# Programmatically Restore Nuget packages

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget-package-restore

I am using MSBuild to programmatically build a solution. The method below works fine only if nuget packages are restored manually in visual studio and "packages" folder exists. However, it doesn't work if "packages" folder does not already exist. The code below does not restore nuget packages, although I have added below 2 lines of code:

- Added **"EnableNuGetPackageRestore"** to globalproperty with "true" value.
- Added **"Restore"**, "Clean", "Build" to target.

Questions:

- What am I missing in below code in order to restore nuget packages before building my solution?
- Is there another programmatic way to use **Nuget.PackageManagement** nuget library to restore nuget packages?

```
// Note: I have referenced version 16.10.0 of Microsoft.Build, Microsoft.Build.Framework,
// and Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.Utilities nuget packages 
private void BuildSolution(string solutionFile)
{
    ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();
    Dictionary globalProperty = new Dictionary();
    globalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Debug");
    globalProperty.Add("Platform", "Any CPU");
    globalProperty.Add("OutputPath", @"bin\Debug");
    globalProperty.Add("EnableNuGetPackageRestore", "true");    // Note: This should restore nuget package?
    BuildParameters bp = new BuildParameters(pc);
    
    // Set the logfile parameter to indicate the log destination
    Microsoft.Build.Logging.FileLogger fileLogger = new Microsoft.Build.Logging.FileLogger();
    fileLogger.Parameters = @"logfile=" + logFilePath;
    bp.Loggers = new List { fileLogger }.AsEnumerable();

    // Note: I have included "Restore" in targets
    BuildRequestData buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(solutionFile, globalProperty, null, 
                  new string[] { "Restore", "Clean", "Build" }, null);
    
    // Run MS Build with specified parameters
    BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(bp, buildRequest);
}
```

**Note**: I do not want to use command line approach such as below.

1. msbuild.exe /t:restore
2. nuget.exe /restore
3. execute Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)